# i want to update my old array with new elements

Tags: objective-c

I want to save my new edited text in my textfield `txt1` in `arr2` and then using the replace method for replacing the new text with the old element in `arry1`. But it doesn't work.

```
arr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[arr2 addObject:txt1.text];
NSInteger j=0;
[arry1 replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:arr2];
[arry1 insertObject:arr2 atIndex:j];
txt1.text=[arry1 objectAtIndex:j];
```

Comment: Please try to give a clearer explanation of _exactly_ what it is you're trying to accomplish. What you've written so far is difficult to understand. Also, please try to format your code so that it's more readable by not putting everything on one line. Stack Overflow is a great place to get help with questions about programming, but it's easier for us to help you if you ask questions in a clear, detailed, precise way.

Answer (score 5):

There are several problems with your code:

```
NSInteger j = 0;
[arry1 replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:arr2];
[arry1 insertObject:arr2 atIndex:j];
```

Replacing means delete the object at the index and insert the new object at the index in one step. What you do is simply adding two times the same thing. You can test that by printing out the array (`NSLog(@"%@",arry1);`).

Next problem:

```
txt1.text=[arry1 objectAtIndex:j];
```

You are storing a `NSArray` in your *arry1* object. However the `NSTextField` expects a string to be the `text` property. You have stored that in *arr2* so you can access it by using this line:

```
txt1.text = [[arry1 objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Always keep in mind what types and structures you are using!